# Воронка и ворона — родственные ли слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Подумалось: а какая связь между словами "ворона" и "воронка"? Вроде как птица на яму от снаряда или посуду не похожа. Или слова просто созвучны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ворон, ворона

От праслав. формы *vorna, от которой в числе прочего произошли: русск.-церк.-слав. врана (κορώνη), укр. воро́на, болг. вра́на, сербохорв. вра̏на, словенск. vrána, чешск. vrána, словацк. vrana, польск. wrona, кашуб. varna, словин. vãrna. Исконнородственно лит. várna «ворона», др.-прусск. warne — то же. Праслав. *vorna, лит. várna < *u̯ōrnā (от *u̯ornos "ворон"): ворона обозначается как связанная с вороном. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера  с комментариями Трубачева;

Воронка

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: укр. воро́нка, болг. вра́на «пробка, втулка», сербохорв. вра̑њ «запор, втулка», словенск. vrȃnj — то же, чешск. vrana «отверстие», польск. wrona — то же. Ср. латышск. vārna «колода с желобками для витья веревок». Сравнивают с алб. varrë «рана» и др.-инд. vraṇás, vraṇám «рана». Вероятно, к вера́ть и польск. wór «мешок». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;

Получается, что изначально слова, от которых произошли интересующие нас, обозначали разные явления (предметы), но очень походили друг на друга фонетически. И это сходство осталось и в образованных словах.

Answer (score 0):

Стаи перелетных ворон летают воронками.
В каком-то месте, возможно, где теплые потоки воздуха, стая останавливается и набирает высоту, кружась на месте, образуя воронку, затем дальше летят.

Comment: Возможно... Разве вороны перелётные? Они же зимующие!